# Better invite system for Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, old-teams

Right now, the only way to add users to a team (that I can see) is to give them a special secret link.

Emailing a link around might work for 'normal' companies, but for Charcoal (where we don't necessarily share emails) it's be nice to be able to point to a specific *user* I want to invite, much like GitHub's organization system:

[image]

This would generate an inbox notification for the user, which they could then accept or reject.

Thoughts?

Comment: Part of the danger here is spamming users - for example everyone pinging Jon Skeet would not be awesome. That would be a reason *not* to do this...

Comment: @NickCraver What about generating per-user per-team URLs that I can paste in chat?

Comment: Generating a specific link for a specific user? Yeah sure - that means *you* have a communication mechanism to the user. I can totally see that happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional invite mechanisms are planned for the public beta.

We're not *sure* yet whether searching by user name (or URL) will be one of them, but it probably will be!

Comment: You don't have to offer search / auto-completion for user names, but sending out unique invites to specific users is certainly needed to avoid the invitation link being shared. One way to reduce the risk of spamming is to only allow users with a minimum reputation to create teams (and invite members).

Answer (score 7):

The inbox notification could work well with 3 (simple) modifications...

To avoid spamming highly coveted users, like Herr Skeet:

1. Aggregate the invites onto an invite page, see below.
2. Throttle the inbox notifications to once per day. But don't send any more notices if a previous notice remains unread.
3. Provide an easy checkbox to turn off all such notices.

So, Jon Skeet might get a notice like:

[image: Aggregate team invite]

The link goes to a *private* page that looks something like this:

[image: invite page mockup]